# Solubility of Calcium Oxalate in Aqueous Alcohol?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, alcohols

In searching through the literature for the solubility of calcium oxalate, I came across this post https://www.researchgate.net/post/Are_there_any_organic_inorganic_solvents_for_dissolving_Ca-oxalate I am not sure where the people answering this question have gotten the information that calcium oxalate is soluble in an aqueous solution of alcohol, but I can't view the only article that I could find agreeing with them past its abstract (I can't see the full text).  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/641826  Does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: I think it depends on what you define as "soluble." Wikipedia states that the solubility in water is 0.67 mg/L (20 °C) which should be more than the solubility would be in pure ethanol.

Comment: Actually calcium oxalate is a lot more [soluble in ethanol](http://digitalcommons.uri.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1212&context=theses#page=20).